# How can I manage blocking code inside gRPC-java server method?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

Let's assume that I have a grpc-java server with code as something like this:

```
@Override
public void getData(RequestValue requestValue, StreamObserver<ResponseValue>responseObserver) {
   ResponseValue rv = ... // blocking code here
   responseObserver.onNext(rv);
   responseObserver.onCompleted();
}
```

So I have a responseValue as a result of blocking code (data from database or other service).

I want to avoid blocking my current thread using another thread-pool for my blocking tasks. For example, in Netty I can use specific EventExecutorGroup for such tasks.

How can I manage it properly with grpc-java service?

Comment: Is your gRPC `getData` method a streaming call? gRCP streaming calls are designed to be long-lived, thus you can just call `onCompleted()` once you are done with the long-running blocking task. You do not necessarily have to create a new thread, as each time an RPC call is made, a new thread is created (which is handled by gRPC in the background).

Comment: @AnonymousAngelo by default grpc-workers uses CachedThreadPool which is wasteful under high load. That's why I want to set fixedThreadPool for workers and another pool for blocking-I/O tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to do this is pass the responseObserver to the long running task:

```
@Override
public void getData(RequestValue requestValue, StreamObserver<ResponseValue> responseObserver) {
    Runnable r = () -> {
        try {
            ResponseValue rv = ... // blocking code here
            responseObserver.onNext(rv);
            responseObserver.onCompleted();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseObserver.onError(e);
    }
    executor.schedule(r);
}
```

It is important that you complete the call at some time, even if an unexpected error occurs. Otherwise you will leak calls (that remain open until the timeout occurs, if ever).

Comment: Damn, why I did not think about this solution?! Thank you.